# When Outlook 2010 opens, it defaults to Send / Receive tab, not Home tab (Ribbon is maximized)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

when one of my users opens Outlook 2010, it defaults to the Send / Receive tab, instead of the Home tab. The ribbon is maximized. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you have been experimenting with options?

```
File Menu
...
Options
Customize Ribbon

Main Tabs
Up Arrow
(Down Arrow for Send / Receive tab)
```

[image: Outlook Ribbon]

Comment: yea we ended up figuring out that the Send/Receive tab was at the top of the list on the right, and when we dragged the Home (Mail) tab back up that resolved the issue! At first I did a repair MS Office in appwiz.cpl and that didnt do anything.